# Using NSURLConnection Asynchronous URL Request with Block Parameter

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm attempting to appropriately use NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest method but I'm having trouble with the block parameter. I built the block above the call and am using __block variables to attempt to retrieve the data collected within it. I've confirmed that the data within the block is correct so the block is working just fine, leaving the retrieval of the block data the problem. My assignments and return statement at the end of the method are not being handed the correct values and I assume it is because the the block has yet to finish executing before the assignment is taking place. How can I "wait" until the block has finished executing before performing the assignments without interrupting the main thread?

```
- (NSData *) sendAsynchronousURLRequest: (NSMutableURLRequest *)request withResponse: (NSURLResponse *)response andError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Prepare the block handler.
    __block NSURLResponse *retrievedBlockResponse;
    __block NSError *retrievedBlockError;
    __block NSData *retrivedBlockData;
    void(^requestHandler)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*) =
    ^(NSURLResponse *blockResponse, NSData *blockData, NSError *blockError)
    {
        retrievedBlockResponse = blockResponse;
        retrivedBlockData = blockData;
        retrievedBlockError = blockError;

        // NOTE: Correct data is here...
        NSLog(@"Data Inside Block:\n%@", [NSMutableDictionary DictionaryFromJSONData:blockData errorReport:nil]);
    };

    // Send the asynchronous request (operationQueue initialized elsewhere in class).
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:requestHandler];

    // NOTE: Reference to data cannot be established here!
    // Establish references to block variables and return NSData object.
    response = retrievedBlockResponse;
    error = retrievedBlockError;
    return retrivedBlockData;
}
```

Comment: The block is sent asynchronously; which means it will return at any time, and yes, mostly likely after the code after it runs. Just do the work you want to do *inside* the block. That'll mean you probably won't be able to return anything from the method, but it's probably just a small change in your networking flow.